# How to display value of custom fields in page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, theme-development

I have a custom post type called 'software', contained within are various custom fields such as subtitle, price, screenshots, download link, etc. I created a function to allow use of the tinyMCE edit window for some of these custom fields. I have been trying to display these fields on the page but with no success.

The method I'm using is this:

```
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
<h3><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'subtitle', TRUE); ?></h3>
```

[Here is a link](http://www.dvmac.co.uk/audioraiders/software/sasha-soundlab-2/) to the page.

Below the `<hr/>` on the page is a list of all the meta created. The ONLY one of the fields which will display is 'price' for some strange reason.

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: it is indeed the `get_post_meta()` function, and if you are calling it inside the loop, it should work... Unless you're not using the right custom field name. They often come with a prefix if they are implemented via a plugin like meta-box. Can you post the code how you declare your custom fields? A solution would be to open the wp_postmeta table in PhpMyAdmin and search the column `meta_key` for LIKE %...% and specify "subtitle" as meta_key value. You will see exactly under what name Wordpress is storing your custom field.

Comment: I know this is old, but I use this sql to get a list of all meta fields in phpmyadmin: SELECT m.meta_key FROM wp_postmeta m GROUP BY m.meta_key

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, you are using:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'subtitle', TRUE);
```

So, you are saying to Wordpress to get the meta value of the 'subtitle' field and that the returned value be in format of string. See [get_post_meta() docu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

To get all meta data of a post you should use [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) function instead. For example, if you are inside the loop:

```
$custom = get_post_custom();
foreach($custom as $key => $value) {
     echo $key.': '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

This will return all meta data of the post. If you want to check, for example, the "price" meta field:

```
if(isset($custom['price'])) {
    echo 'Price: '.$custom['price'][0];
}
```

Comment: Last code block is missing a )

Comment: it appears that `$custom['price']` returns an array so you may need to do `$custom['price'][0]`

Answer (score 5):

use this code for solving your problem.

```
$key_name = get_post_custom_values($key = 'Key Name');
echo $key_name[0];
```